# U-boot to load two kernel (GPOS and RTOS) on separate CPU (A9 and M3)

Tags: linux, multicore, rtos

I have pandaboard omap4460 development board. My project needs to flash two OS kernels (GPOS and NuttX RTOS) in such a way that linux runs on Cortex-A9 and RTOS on Cortex-M3. I have 1GB LPDDR2 in which I have to allocate first 128MB for RTOS and rest for LINUX image.

How to configure U-boot in this case?

Please let me know some steps if anyone have solved this!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read How do I ask  a good question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The OMAP is the Cortex-A9, but what is the Cortex-M3?